# How to add one year to current year using DateTime

Tags: c#

Currently I have the following where I grab the current year:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now.Year; 
Response.Write(dt1);
```

However, I would like to add one more year to `dt1`. So I did the following:

```
DateTime addYear = dt1.AddYears(1);
```

But it does not like that. What would be the correct approach of adding one more year?

Comment: DateTime.Now.Year returns an Int32, not a DateTime.

Comment: Why don't you try to read the error message and try to understand what it says?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add years to the DateTime, not the year

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
```

Comment: This is not existing on .NET 6

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.Now.Year` is an integer.  None of what you have there should be working quite right. 
This is what you need:

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());     
DateTime addYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
Response.Write(addYear.Year.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Be **very, very** careful.  You are adding a "calendar year" when doing it that way.  Which may or may not be what you intend or expect.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine(start.AddDays(90).AddYears(1));
Console.WriteLine(start.AddYears(1).AddDays(90)); // Different answer!  Try it!
```

Comment: @ Wyck: Thank you for your example. It actually is helping me understand how DateTime works. Thank You